# Force abstract method to execute predefined code - similar to overloaded return statement

Tags: java, inheritance, abstract-class

I have a abstract class with a abstract method

```
 public abstract class Foo{
    public int bar();
}
```

This is inherited and implemented by normal classes using some methods.

```
public class ConcreteFoo1 extends AbstractFoo{
    public void bar(){
    method1();
    method2();
    closingMethod();
    return 1;
```

}
    }

```
public class ConcreteFoo2 extends AbstractFoo{
public void bar(){
    method3();
    method4();
    closingMethod();
    return 2;
```

}
    }

As you can see both classes end with `closingMethod();` To end the implemented `bar()`method with the same line(s) is essential for a framework I work on. Is there a way to enforce that through the parent class. Lacking better words making it "semi abstract" where the first n lines are defined in the child class and the closing lines are defined by the parent. Ideally I would like to overload the `return` statement or implement a "method destructor".

Is there a way to achieve this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I would probably do it by defining a non abstract method in `Foo` in which I would call the abstract method `bar` and the `closingMethod()`, e.g.

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public void foo() {
        bar();
        closingMethod();
    }
    public abstract void bar();
}
```

UPDATE after OP's edit:

Indeed that complicates things a little, however you might do something like

```
public abstract class Foo {
    public int foo() {
        bar();
        closingMethod();
        return baz();
    }
    protected abstract void bar();
    protected abstract int baz();
}
```

Comment: Thats is a good answer to the original question. My bad for giving a faulty example (now edited). I actually need the function to return something and in that case your solution is not working that well.

Comment: @EinarSundgren I've added a solution proposal for the edited question. It's not so nice anymore, but still does the job. It all really depends on how much stuff your classes share...